# Debugging in Intellij

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ and would like to know how do we put break points in the classes under a jar. I am debugging something and would like to put a break point in DispatcherServlet. I have tried to find it everywhere but cannot find it.

Comment: I found it to Navigate to a class using Command+N

Answer (score 1):

You can find your third party dependencies in your Project tab under external libraries. There you can select the class, Idea shows you decompiled code and you can put breakpoint in there.

**External libraries location**
[image]

**Dispatcher Servlet location and breakpoint**
[image]